# In postgresql, how to check the table with a function if already a record satisfies my conditions exist, then update it or insert new one?

Tags: postgresql

I'm using postgresql and I want to insert or update records with a function in my program. But the thing I have to know is, if a record with conditions I look for is already in database, I will update it, else I will insert a new record. With details:

Table :

```
CREATE TABLE running_check
(
  "UID" character varying(100) NOT NULL,
  "CameraIP" character varying(100),
  "ErrorStatus" integer,
  "IsRunning" boolean,
  "CheckTime" timestamp without time zone
);
```

Some example records:

```
UID        CameraIP         ErrorStatus        IsRunnning     CheckTime
------------------------------------------------------------------
12E        10.0.0.26        0                  true           now()
C26        10.0.0.22        0                  true           now()
454        10.0.0.13        3                  false          now()
```

I need a function like:

`InsertRunningCheckInfo(character varying, character varying, integer, boolean )`

And when I call the function, firstly I need to check the records in table 
      if a record with the same UID already exist, 
          then if its "IsRunning" value is true, just update the "CheckTime", 
          else update its ErrorStatus, IsRunning and CheckTime values,
      if a record with the same UID doesn't exist,
          insert a new record.

Actually, the problem I face is about not knowing how to use a Select query in a function to check its fields then do work, because I'm too new to Postgresql, searched for it for a while but couldn't find something useful for me. Maybe another way is available for this task in Postgresql that I don't know, so wanted to ask you.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8702291/330315 plus there are examples of this in the Postgres manual in the chapter about PL/pgSQL programming.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert, on duplicate update (postgresql)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109061/insert-on-duplicate-update-postgresql)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Good or Bad, my solution to my problem:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insertrunningcheckinfo(character varying, character varying, integer, boolean) RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $_$

        DECLARE 
    record_number INTEGER;

BEGIN
 --LOOP

    Select Into record_number "RecordNo" from "running_check" where "UID" = $1 order by "RecordNo" DESC limit  1 ;

    UPDATE "running_check"
    SET   "CheckTime" = now()
        WHERE "RecordNo" = record_number and ("IsRunning" = true and $4 = true);

        IF found THEN
            RETURN;
        END IF;


        UPDATE "running_check"
    SET   "CheckTime" = now()
        WHERE "RecordNo" = record_number and ("IsRunning" = false and $4 = false) and "Status" = $3;

        IF found THEN
            RETURN;
        END IF;

--BEGIN --BEGIN INSERT

    INSERT INTO "running_check"(
            "UID", 
            "CameraIP", 
            "Status",
            "IsRunning",
            "CheckTime")

    VALUES ($1, 
        $2, 
        $3,
        $4,
        now()
        );

    RETURN;
    EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN
    -- Do nothing
--END; --END INSERT
--END LOOP;
END;
$_$;
```

Answer (score 4):

In the body of your [stored procedure](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/plpgsql.html), you can do something like:

```
SELECT UID
FROM running_check
WHERE UID = myparameter;

IF FOUND THEN
  -- UPDATE running_check SET ... WHERE UID = myparameter
ELSE
  -- INSERT INTO running_CHECK ...
END IF;
```

The `found` boolean checks the previous statement for results. I do not have a Postgres environment available to me anymore, so I can't check this. But this should push you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine both the update and the insert into a single statement with a data modifying common table expression, in which the CTE attempts to update the table and an insert in the main clause add a row if the update returned no rows (ie. if it did not find a row to update).

The code would be similar to:

```
with
  cte_update_attempt as (
    update t
    set    col2 = 'f'
    where  col1 = 1
    returning *)
insert into t (
  col1,
  col2)
select
  1,
 'f'
where
  not exists (
    select null
    from   cte_update_attempt);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/7d846/2